# Display different prefix and suffix in CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
$all_categories=get_cats($cat);
$headingPrinted = false;
$childCount = 0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++)
{    
  $arr=get_gender($cat);
  if($arr[$i]=='0')
  {
    if (!$headingPrinted) {
      echo "&nbsp&nbsp"."Sons:";
      $headingPrinted = true;
    }  
    echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i].",";
    $childCount++;
  }
} 

if ($childCount >= 3) {
  echo $childCount,  $childCount == 1 ;  
} 
else {
  // you may want to do something if none found
}

$headingPrinted = false;
$childCount = 0;

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($all_categories);$i++)
{    
  $arr=get_gender($cat);
  if($arr[$i]=='1'){
    if (!$headingPrinted) {
      echo "&nbsp&nbsp"."Daughters:";
      $headingPrinted = true;
    }  
    echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$all_categories[$i].",";
    $childCount++;
  }
} 
if ($childCount >= 3) {
  echo $childCount,  $childCount == 1 ;  
} 
else {
  // you may want to do something if none found
}
```

I am displaying the word "Sons" then their names then their count and the word "daughters" then their names then count. I want to display like this:

> Sons: a,b,c,d:4;
>   Daughters: p,q,r,s:4;

`$all_categories` is an array in which I'm getting all children of given ID and `get_gender` and `get_cats` are functions.

Now I'm displaying:

> a,b,c,d, :4;

I want to display count only if:

- count of sons is greater than 2 and same for daughters.
- boys count is 1 then the word "Sons:"a; and same for daughters.
- boys count is 2 then the word "Sons:" a,b; and same for daughters.
- boys count is greater than 2 then the word "Sons:" a,b,c:3; and same for daughters.

I want to display result same like above I said. Thanks in advance
Anyone tried this...

Comment: I think it would pretty much easier if you got all the data from the database, a good model that will return you all you want

Comment: i m getting all the data but i am not able to display that according to requirement..

Comment: What I mean: a proper model will give you back ALL you're asking for in the model, if you have to count in the controller or if you have to consult data calling again the DDBB with data you got, you probably have design problems.